# React не отрисовывают элементы

Tags: reactjs, redux

У меня есть проблема. У меня есть работающий код, который имел бы отрисовать элементы. Дело в том, что у меня вообще в приложении есть 9 API запросов (это 9). Все компоненты работают, кроме этой компоненты. В консоль этой компоненты, данные я получаю. Скажите, я что-то неправильно делаю ли ограничения на количество запросов. Спасибо большое

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {western_movies_are_loaded} from "../redux/action_creators";

export let Western = () => {

let dispatch = useDispatch();
let western_movies = useSelector(({movies_reducer : {western_movies}}) => western_movies);

let fetchWestern = async () => {
    try {
        let response = await fetch('https://api.sampleapis.com/movies/western');
        let json = await response.json();
        console.log(json);
        dispatch(western_movies_are_loaded(json));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchWestern()
},[])

return (<div>Western
    {western_movies.map(el => <div key={el.id}>
        <p>{el.title}</p>
                            </div>)}
        </div>)
}
```

Reducers.js

```
import {
WESTERN_MOVIES_LOADED
} from "./action_types";

let initialState = {
western_movies : []
}
let movies_reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case WESTERN_MOVIES_LOADED: {
        return {
            ...state,
            western_movies: action.payload
        }
    }
default:
return state;
}
}
export default movies_reducer;
```

action_creators.js

```
import {
WESTERN_MOVIES_LOADED
} from "./action_types";
let western_movies_are_loaded = (payload) => ({type: WESTERN_MOVIES_LOADED, payload});
export {
western_movies_are_loaded
}
```

Comment: Возможно в редаксе проблема, данные добавляются и приходят из Редакса? Добавьте в компонент: `console.log(`western_movies`, western_movies)
`

Comment: @KonstantinModin, да, я работаю с редаксом. 8 запросов у меня работают, 9 - нет. Я написал `console.log(western_movies)` и получил пустой массив

Comment: значит данные не попадают в редакс, добавь код редюсера и action

Comment: @KonstantinModin уже добавил

Comment: не вижу ошибки здесь, может проект есть на гитхабе, или в песочнице ?

Comment: @KonstantinModin https://github.com/Dmytrii9Cherniak/Movie.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Была опечатка в action_types. Должно быть:

```
let MYSTERY_MOVIES_LOADED = "MYSTERY_MOVIES_LOADED";
let WESTERN_MOVIES_LOADED = "WESTERN_MOVIES_LOADED";
```

Да и как совет: я бы поменял все `let` на `const`

Comment: Йомайо, целый день потратил на ошибку эту ... Большое спасибо)))

Comment: Пожалуйста, отметь ответ как правильный если всё ок (+лайк), спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй дописать проверку `{western_movies && western_movies.map(el => <div key={el.id}>`

Скорее всего на момент вызова метода map, масив western_movies пустой

Comment: спасибо, но не помогло...

Comment: Закинь fetchWestern в useEffect, попробуй так

Comment: У меня функция и запускается в useEffect, но ничего не дает. Если забросить всю функцию fetchWestern в useEffect, результат такой же (((

Comment: Да, прости, не подумал